# Некорректно собирается артефакт в Intelij Idea

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

Некорректно собирается артефакт в Intelij Idea:

> Error: Could not find or load main
> class product.jar

Main class в настройках артефактов указал.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: арт**е**факт

Comment: идеи есть ?